# Route multiple users to a specific Kubernetes pod based on the data they access

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple pods of the same app deployed using Kubernetes. The app manages multiple 'Project' objects. When Marry is working on 'Project 1' on pod-01, Tom logs on pod-02. Here is the requirement, if Tom tries to open 'Project 1' on pod-02, we need to route him to pod-01 where 'Project 1' is already open by Marry. How would I do that?

Can I store some unique identifier of pod-01 in the 'Project 1' object? So I can use it to route Tom to pod-01.

Is this technically feasible?

Comment: I think Kubernetes doesn't support such routing by itself. But you can consider implementing a service mesh like Istio (See: [Route based on user identity](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity))

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is **stateful** workload, where each instance of your application contain *state*.

*Normal* workload in Kubernetes is **stateless** and deployed with [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/). However, Kubernetes now has *some* support for **stateful** workloads by using [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

It may be possible to implement your use case, but it depends. Your users will not have an instance for themself if that is what you need. I would recommend you to architect your service to be **stateless** workload, and store all state in a database (possibly with statefulSet) since it is much easier to handle stateless workloads.

Comment: I am working with a legacy application which already support such use case, without using Kubernetes. Refactoring the application to be stateless currently is not an option.